# Blank space in Geocoding sample app

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-maps

Why if I copied code from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation, when I start the app I see all blank space? I use emulator Nexus9.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Geolocation</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>

    <script>
// Note: This example requires that you consent to location sharing when
// prompted by your browser. If you see a blank space instead of the map, this
// is probably because you have denied permission for location sharing.

var map;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 6
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  // Try HTML5 geolocation
  if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                       position.coords.longitude);

      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        map: map,
        position: pos,
        content: 'Location found using HTML5.'
      });

      map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
      handleNoGeolocation(true);
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleNoGeolocation(false);
  }
}

function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
  if (errorFlag) {
    var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
  } else {
    var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
  }

  var options = {
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
    content: content
  };

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
  map.setCenter(options.position);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I use it on Eclipse.

Comment: Did you consent to location sharing as the note asks?

Comment: LOL @mattfred I do love to see captain obvious save the day. even if this isnt the answer, love it.

Comment: I have add uses permission (.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS).   And on device GPS is turn

Comment: is `blank space`.color=='gray'..? if so it is loading, just slowly, some time it take minutes for me in the emulator.

Comment: I wait 5 minutes, but nothing is changed. I try on a Samsung Galaxy S4Mini, but I have the same problem.. And yes it is gray

Comment: one problem of this code is it is waiting for the gps to return the location before it display the map... add `handleNoGeolocation(true);` before `if(navigator.geolocation) {          // Try HTML5 geolocation` would force it to load the maps before it waits for the location. PS. being gray means Google maps loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change this:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
```

To this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=set_to_true_or_false"></script>
```